# Error when trying to use typeorm migration with ts-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I'm encountering an issue when trying to run migrations in a TypeORM project using ts-node. Despite my attempts to troubleshoot, I keep running into a runtime error related to a custom utility function, deepFlatten, and issues opening my database configuration file.

**Environment:**

Node.js version: v14.5.1
TypeORM version: 0.3.17
ts-node version: 10.9.1
Project setup: TypeScript with a mix of JS for configuration files

**Issue Description:**

When I attempt to run a TypeORM migration command via yarn scripts, I encounter the following error:

```
Error during migration run:
Error: Unable to open file: "/Users/nikola/poddster-maintenence-saas/poddster/backend/src/config/_database.js". (0 , utils_1.deepFlatten) is not a function
    at Function.loadDataSource (/Users/nikola/poddster-maintenence-saas/poddster/backend/node_modules/src/commands/CommandUtils.ts:22:19)
    at async Object.handler (/Users/nikola/poddster-maintenence-saas/poddster/backend/node_modules/src/commands/MigrationRunCommand.ts:42:26)
```

**database.js Configuration:**

Here's a simplified version of my _database.js file, which is used to configure the TypeORM data source:

```
    import { DataSource } from "typeorm";
import { BaseEntity } from "../entity/BaseEntity";
// Additional imports...

const dataSourceCache = new Map();

export const initializeDatabase = async dbName => {
  // Initialization logic...
};

// Database configuration
function getDatabaseConfig(dbName) {
  return {
    type: "postgres",
    // Other configuration...
    entities: [
      BaseEntity,
      // Other entities...
    ],
  };
}

const defaultDbName = process.env.DB_NAME || "default";
export const defaultDataSource = new DataSource(getDatabaseConfig(defaultDbName));
```

**Yarn Script:**

My package.json script to run migrations looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm"
}
```

And the command I run is:

yarn typeorm migration:run -- -d ./src/config/_database.js

**Attempts to Resolve:**

I've verified that ts-node is installed and accessible.
Ensured that my tsconfig.json correctly configures path aliases and matches my project structure.
Simplified the _database.js file to isolate the issue, without success.

**Question:**

How can I resolve the error related to deepFlatten and ensure my TypeORM migrations run successfully with ts-node in my setup? Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide insight into why ts-node might be having trouble with my configuration?

**Update:**

After receiving suggestions, I've also tried directly invoking TypeORM CLI commands with ts-node by updating my script in package.json as follows:

```
"typeorm": "node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"
```

and I also tried typeorm-ts-node-commonjs with same results:

```
Error during migration run:
Error: Unable to open file: "/Users/nikola/poddster-maintenence-saas/poddster/backend/src/config/_database.js". Cannot find module '~/environment'
Require stack:
- /Users/nikola/poddster-maintenence-saas/poddster/backend/src/utils/_throw-error.js
- /Users/nikola/poddster-maintenence-saas/poddster/backend/src/utils/index.js
- /Users/nikola/poddster-maintenence-saas/poddster/backend/src/entity/Booking.ts
- /Users/nikola/poddster-maintenence-saas/poddster/backend/src/config/_database.js
- /Users/nikola/poddster-maintenence-saas/poddster/backend/node_modules/typeorm/util/ImportUtils.js
- /Users/nikola/poddster-maintenence-saas/poddster/backend/node_modules/typeorm/commands/CommandUtils.js
- /Users/nikola/poddster-maintenence-saas/poddster/backend/node_modules/typeorm/commands/SchemaSyncCommand.js
- /Users/nikola/poddster-maintenence-saas/poddster/backend/node_modules/typeorm/cli.js
```

But in my tsconfig I have:

```
"paths": {
      "~/*": ["src/*"],
```